# How can i return a custom statusCode and body if a get an error in aws Lamda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to do something like this, but keeps returning statusCode: 200 and statusMessage: "OK"

```
except Exception as e:
    response = {
        'statusCode': 404,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        'body': {
            "error": "{0}".format(e)
        }
    }
    return json.dumps(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless your lambda function fails. Any successful execution of lambda is 200. The fact that you are catching exception and returning 404, indicates that lambda executed correctly.